Postman: How to iterate over query parameters and save the responses into a single file?
I have to make GET calls to an api endpoint which will retrieve records. In the query, there is a parameter called p which denotes page number. P can vary from 1 to 20. I want to automatically iterate 20 times and then store the responses into one single file. How can I achieve this using Postman?

You can do it using newman library by node.js
Demo
I am using this Get API with page option
if change page number, the response will be change too.
https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1


I made 5 requests by Postman with different page.
You can add up to 20 page.

Export it
Save as 1-demo.postman_collection.json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "b0791408-a367-47c1-a96c-3b305a634c10",
        "name": "1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get facts page 1",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "SOAPAction",
                        "value": "http://tempuri.org/sum",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": []
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "catfact",
                        "ninja"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "facts"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get facts page 2",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "SOAPAction",
                        "value": "http://tempuri.org/sum",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": []
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=2",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "catfact",
                        "ninja"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "facts"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get facts page 3",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "SOAPAction",
                        "value": "http://tempuri.org/sum",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": []
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=3",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "catfact",
                        "ninja"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "facts"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get facts page 4",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "SOAPAction",
                        "value": "http://tempuri.org/sum",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": []
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "catfact",
                        "ninja"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "facts"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get facts page 5",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "SOAPAction",
                        "value": "http://tempuri.org/sum",
                        "type": "text",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": []
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "catfact",
                        "ninja"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "facts"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "variable": [
        {
            "key": "priductIds",
            "value": "[\"1001\", \"1002\", \"1003\", \"1004\", \"3002\"]",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "priductId",
            "value": "1001",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "baseUrl",
            "value": "https://valentinos-coffee.herokuapp.com",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}

node.js program
Save as demo.js
const newman = require('newman');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    collection: './1-demo.postman_collection.json',
};

newman.run(options, function (err, summary) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Newman run encountered an error:', err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Newman run completed successfully!');

    const responsesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'responses');
    if (!fs.existsSync(responsesDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(responsesDir);
    }

    // Initialize an empty array
    const allResponses = [];

    // Process each executed request
    summary.run.executions.forEach(function (execution) {
        const request = execution.request;
        const response = execution.response;

        // Check if response object is defined
        if (response && response.stream) {
            // Convert Uint8Array data to human-readable text
            const responseData = Buffer.from(response.stream).toString('utf8');
        
            // Parse the response data to JSON object
            let jsonResponse;
            try {
                jsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error parsing response data:', error);
                return;
            }
        
            // Append the response data
            allResponses.push(jsonResponse);
        } else {
            console.error('Error: No stream data found for response');
        }
    });

    // After processing all responses, write the allResponses array to a single JSON file
    const filePath = path.join(responsesDir, 'output.json');
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(allResponses, null, 4), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error writing all response data to file:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('All response data saved to output.json');
        }
    });
});

Install dependencies
npm install newman fs path

File tree

If not install node.js, install from here
Run demo.js
node demo.js

Result
The output.json will save into response directory

